# Resource designer cs does not update

Tags: android, xml, xamarin

When I change my `Main.axml` as follows, then I am losing connection `Resource.designer.cs` does not affected or updated, therefore, I could not able to assign resources id.

I would like to know where I am doing wrong.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2">
    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/aView"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:layout_width="100"
        android:layout_height="25"
        android:text="1" />
    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/bView"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="2" />
    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/cView"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="3" />
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your AXML file set with a build action of AndroidResource, and located in the Resources/Layout folder of your Android project?

Cheers,
Tristan